# Insert Low Variables Between Channel Entries

Tags: channel-entries, low-variables

On the home page of a site I am displaying a series of articles. In between each of these articles I wish to display a banner ad controlled via Low Variables.

At the moment it repeats the first ad between each channel entry instead of correctly looping through the banner ads.

Here is what I have so far:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="articles" limit="14" disable="categories|category-fields|member-data"}

<article>
<p>{article_subtitle}</p>
<h1><a href="{title_permalink='articles/view'}">{title}</a></h1>
<figure><a href="{title_permalink='articles/view'}">
{article_images cover_only="yes"}
<img src="{image:url:large}" alt="{image:title}" />
{/article_images}
</a></figure>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<a href="{title_permalink='articles/view'}">Further reading +</a>
</article>


{exp:low_variables:parse var="banner_ads" multiple="yes" limit="1"}
<div class="banner-ad">
<a href="{banner_ads_link}"><img src="{banner_ads_image_desktop}" /></a>
</div>
{/exp:low_variables:parse}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the Low Variables variable type?

Comment: Matrix. It consists of 2 columns: an image and a link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to do this with the help of [Math](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/math):

```
{exp:low_variables:parse
    var="banner_ads"
    offset="{exp:math formula='{count}-1'}"
    limit="1"
    parse="inward"
}
```

Comment: Math: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/math